# I have a text field in html.Now i want to take the data from the html page and import it to my JSP page.How to do that?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I have created the input form in html.Now to accept the data in my jsp page should I assign a string variable to accept the data in jsp Or what variable should I use.I want to store the data in mysql,There also I have created a text column.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use a variable if you want to get your data simply call a servlet in the action of your form -
action = "SERVELT-NAME"

Comment: Could you please elaborate I didn't understand what you meant.Coz i am a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple example

1/ you create a jsp page where you put your form with inputs

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title> My first JSP   </title>
    </head> 
    <body>      
        <form action="HelloServlet" method="GET">           
             Please enter a color <br>
            <input type="text" name="color" >
            <input type="submit" value="submit">                        
        </form>     
    </body> 
</html>
```

2/ create a servlet :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet { 
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
    String color= request.getParameter("color");   
      // HERE CALL A METHOD TO STORE DATA IN DATABASE exp insertInDB(color);

    request.setAttribute("mycolor", color);// if you want to see your data
     request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);

  }  
}
```

3/ create another JSP page (test.jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title> My first JSP   </title>
    </head> 
    <body>      

          the color is : ${mycolor}         

    </body> 
</html>
```

4/ in your web.xml file you should have (or put)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing,i will try to understand and try it.